# Website looks ok in IE7 but not other IEs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility

[image]
This is how my website looks in Google Chrome and nearly all browsers except some versions of IE.

[image]
This is how it looks in IE8, IE9 and probably in IE6.

The funny thing is that the website looks ABSOLUTELY ok in IE7. I want you to help me solve the problem, but I don't really know which data to server you, but if you ask, I can provide everything you need.

**Here's the header code:**

```
<div id="header">
<div id="headercont">
<div id="headerlogo">
<img src="<?php echo dir;?>css/images/headerbg.png" class="header" />
</div>
<div id="menu">
<div id="mpointshighlight">
<div id="menupoints">

<?php echo menuSpace; ?>
<a href="<?php echo dir;?>index.php"><div id="menumain">Main</div></a>
<?php echo menuSpace; ?>
<a href="<?php echo dir;?>about.php"><div id="menuabout">About</div></a>
<?php echo menuSpace; ?>
<a href="<?php echo dir;?>blog.php"><div id="menublog">Blog</div></a>
<?php echo menuSpace; ?>
<a href="<?php echo dir;?>photos/photos.php"><div id="menuphotos">Photos</div></a>
<?php echo menuSpace; ?>
<a href="<?php echo dir;?>videos.php"><div id="menuvideos">Videos</div></a>
<?php echo menuSpace; ?>
<a href="<?php echo dir;?>music.php"><div id="menumusic">Music</div></a>
<?php echo menuSpace; ?>
<a href="<?php echo dir;?>projects/projects.php"><div id="menuprojects">Projects</div></a>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Here's the header CSS:**

```
#header {
background-color:#00a2ff;
background-image:url('images/menubg.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:bottom;
width:100%;
min-width:1100px;
height:243px;
}

#headercont {
margin:auto;
width:1100px;
}
#headerlogo {
margin:auto;
width:1000px;
}
#menu {
width:100%;
height:44px;
}
#menupoints {
position:relative;
width:1000px;
font-size:24px;
font-family:verdana;
height:44px;
}
#mpointshighlight {
margin:auto;
width:1000px;
margin-bottom:10px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#menupoints a:link {
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow: black 2px 2px 3px;
}
#menupoints a:visited {
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow: gray 2px 2px 3px;
}
#menupoints a:hover {
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow: black 2px 2px 3px, white 0 0 1em;
}
#menupoints a:active {
}
#menumain {
display:inline
}
#menuabout {
display:inline
}
#menublog {
display:inline
}
#menuphotos {
display:inline
}
#menuvideos {
display:inline
}
#menumusic {
display:inline
}
#menuprojects {
display:inline
}
```

Comment: Post your code, something is wrong with your js or css

Comment: **Here is the header**:
`<div id="header">
<div id="headercont">
<div id="headerlogo">
<img src="<?php echo dir;?>css/images/headerbg.png" class="header" />
</div>
<div id="menu">
<div id="mpointshighlight">
<div id="menupoints">

<?php echo menuSpace; ?>
<a href="<?php echo dir;?>index.php"><div id="menumain">Main</div></a>
<?php echo menuSpace; ?>
<a href="<?php echo dir;?>about.php"><div id="menuabout">About</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: **Here is the CSS**:
`#header {
background-color:#00a2ff;
background-image:url('images/menubg.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:bottom;
width:100%;
min-width:1100px;
height:243px;
}

#headercont {
margin:auto;
width:1100px;
}
#headerlogo {
margin:auto;
width:1000px;
}
#menu {
width:100%;
height:44px;
}
#menupoints {
position:relative;
width:1000px;
font-size:24px;
font-family:verdana;
height:44px;
}
#mpointshighlight {
margin:auto;
width:1000px;
margin-bottom:10px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be certain what the problem is without going into depth, but something that might help is to look into compatibility modes in IE:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Specifically, tell IE8 and higher to emulate IE7:

Ensure this is the first HTML tag in the head.

As for IE6, depending on your target audience, you might be able to get away with ignoring it, otherwise it's a trawl through CSS I'm afraid!